# Embedded Ruby GC and wrapped structs

Tags: c++, ruby, garbage-collection

I have a win32 console application with ruby 1.9.3 embedded, and I am having problems with ruby GC and objects with wrapped C structs that include a pointer to big data.

After some testing, ruby seems to run the GC when the orphaned objects are taking up some memory. The problem is that ruby does not take into account the memory size the struct pointer is taking up, so it won't start the GC as it thinks that those orphaned objects are too small and do not take up much memory.

I have made an example app that will crash as it creates lots of objects with big data in their wrapped struct, here is the code:

```
#include <ruby.h>

typedef struct TestClassStructS {
    byte* bytes;
} TestClassStruct;

static void testClassFree(TestClassStruct *p) {
    delete p->bytes;
    delete p;
}

VALUE testClassNew(VALUE klass) {
    TestClassStruct* ptr = new TestClassStruct();
    ptr->bytes = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 5]();
    VALUE obj = Data_Wrap_Struct(klass, NULL, testClassFree, ptr);
    rb_obj_call_init(obj, 0, 0);
    return obj;
}

VALUE testClassInitialize(VALUE self) {
    return self;
}

typedef VALUE (*rubyfunc)(...);

VALUE require_wrap(VALUE arg)
{
    return rb_eval_string("GC.enable; loop do; TestClass.new; end");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{
    RUBY_INIT_STACK;
    ruby_init();
    //freopen("CON", "w", stdout);
    ruby_init_loadpath();
    ruby_sysinit(&argc, argv);

    VALUE testClass = rb_define_class("TestClass", rb_cObject);
    rb_define_singleton_method(testClass, "new", (rubyfunc)testClassNew, 0);
    rb_define_method(testClass, "initialize", (rubyfunc)testClassInitialize, 0);

    int error;
    VALUE result = rb_protect(require_wrap, 0, &error);
    if (error) 
    {
        VALUE lasterr = rb_gv_get("$!");
        VALUE message = rb_obj_as_string(lasterr);

        printf(StringValuePtr(message));
    }

    return ruby_cleanup(0);
}
```

This is not a real case scenario, but makes me worry that in some cases my app could take too much memory if the GC is not started.

I could fix this problem making regular calls to GC.start, but it seems like a dirty solution for me.

If there was a way for making ruby to prioritize garbage collection when some objects are orphaned or to tell ruby the real size the c struct occupies in memory, would be a nice solution, but I do not know if ruby api includes something like this, I could not find anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, use xmalloc (from ruby.h I think) to allocate the memory. That is, so far, the only way to make sure that the allocated memory gets accounted for the next GC trigger.

There is a new dsize function registered with wrapped C structs, but it seems that it is not (yet ?) used in ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Thanks, that does it. The only problem is that if you don't control the memory allocation (e.g. the memory gets allocated in an external lib) you can't use xmalloc. But maybe I can manage to make it work, probably by changing a bit  gc.c

Could you point me to some information about the new dsize function?

Comment: I have the same general problem (big structures allocated from C++, need to tell Ruby's GC about it). If you are fine with having a patched Ruby, I would recommend simply adding a public method, like rb_gc_announce_malloc(size) or something like that which allows to tell the GC that there is some memory allocated. I'm not sure about the dsize method.